# Run java application from command line with external jar files

Tags: java, command-line, jar, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I have an external jar file(have package structure), which contains the main class, and I can run the app from command line like this:

```
java -jar example.jar
```

But I still have another `test.class` file outside this jar file, and some classes inside this jar file will invoke the methods in `test.class`. How can I specify the `test.class` file to be used by jar file in command line?  Tried many ways, always show:

```
NoClassDefFoundError for test.class
```

NB: the test.class file also use class files in example.jar file, has its own package structure.

I know I can put them together in one jar file, unfortunately I need separate the test.class file.

Comment: Read up on Classpaths in the oracle tutorial.

Answer (score 16):

If the class is in bin directory :

```
java -cp xxx.jar;bin pck1.pck2.MainClass
```

If the class is in the current directory :

```
java -cp xxx.jar;. pck1.pck2.MainClass
```

and so on...

[More info in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), please read it at least one time... ;-)

Comment: Sorry, not in workspace, no bin directory. Assume test.class file is in the same folder with example.jar file

Comment: *"Assume test.class file is in the same folder with example.jar file"*  How about you 'pick up the ball & run with it' rather than try to get us to code this to your exact specification?

Comment: I think I forgot to mention one important thing: the test.class also use the class files in example.jar, and has its own package structure too...and you use ; to separate class path to search the class files?

Comment: Seriously how hard is `java.exe -?`

Comment: @Aubin I was asking LifeOnCodes lol. This question could have been summed up for him if he had just done `java.exe -?`.

Comment: It works. I want to stress that the options `-cp xxx.jar;.` should come before the class containing the main method, otherwise the annoying "Error: Could not find or load main class" appears.

Answer (score 9):

**In Linux System**

Compile and Run Java Program along with External JARs.

```
javac -cp </path/jar1>:<path/jar2>:<path/jar3> MainClass.java
```

If Compiler throws deprecation warning. You can recompile with **-Xlint:deprecation** argument.

```
javac -Xlint:deprecation -cp </path/jar1>:<path/jar2>:<path/jar3> MainClass.java
```

Finally, run the Java Program:

```
java -cp </path/jar1>:<path/jar2>:<path/jar3>:. MainClass
```

If you want to run Java Process in Background. You can use **nohup**.

```
nohup java -cp </path/jar1>:<path/jar2>:<path/jar3>:. MainClass &
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use following commands to run java main class or java jar file:

```
java -Djava.ext.dirs=E:\lib  E:\Executable\MyMainClass

java -Djava.ext.dirs=E:\lib  E:\Executable\purging.jar
```