# java compile failed where classpath with jar files

Tags: java, javac

There is a `jar` named `353.jar` in a directory. I new a java class and import a class that is in `353.jar`.

```
import com.coxier.test.DrawaerLayout;


class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawaerLayout d = new DrawaerLayout();
    }
}
```

I compile `Test.java` with below command:

```
javac -verbose -classpath /Users/coxier/test/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/353.jar:. TestA.java
```

But here is a error:

`error: package com.coxier.test does not exist`

## EDIT 1

Thanks @Marquis. I know this jar is a dex format file.

`jar tvf 351.jar`

The output is:
`1080024 Thu Jul 02 17:52:10 CST 2020 classes.dex`

Comment: What's *in* the JAR file?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I use `jadx-gui` and I see there is a class file in 353.jar.

Comment: You see *what* class file? under what path?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne A `DrawaerLayout.class` in `com.coxier.test` package.

Comment: I didn't ask about the package, I asked about the *path*. Make an effort.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne How can I know the path ? I use `jadx-gui` to see jar file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217083/discussion-between-coxier-and-marquis-of-lorne).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run java application from command line with external jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657849/run-java-application-from-command-line-with-external-jar-files)

Comment: @Raghuveer Thanks but this is not my question.

Comment: You can list the whole JAR file with `jar tvf 353.jar`. Do that and post the line containing the filename of the class in question.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Thanks a lot. I got `995648 Thu Jul 02 17:52:10 CST 2020 classes.dex`

Comment: So it didn't contain `DrawaerLayout.class` at all, contrary to what you claimed above. So this is what you need to fix. It should contain a file named `/com/coxier/test/DrawaerLayout.class` for your command line to work.

Comment: Where does it say that `javac` understands JAR files containing DEX files?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Yes javac can not read dex files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javac has nothing to do with android.

Android development can be done using a language that is extremely java like but not quite java. In particular, all the infrastructure around it, such as what the compiled code looks like, is entirely non-java (as in, the tooling that ships with not-android-targeted java, such as your OpenJDK installation, doesn't know about it and can't read any of it).

That jar file contains, as far as java itself is concerned (and javac is just java, not android), absolutely nothing: It has no idea what a dex file is, so that is just ignored.

This code would work if the jar file contained the entry:

`/com/coxier/test/DrawaerLayout/Test.class`

then, `javac -cp thatJar.jar TestA.java` would work, assuming `TestA.java` is in the current working directory and contains:

```
import com.coxier.test.DrawaerLayout.Test;

public class TestA {
    Test test;
}
```

If you have the source of that `Test.dex` file, you could make a class file instead, but it sounds like what you need is for `TestA.java` to also be compiled with the android toolkit, which presumably does know what dex files are, and may even accept them in jars (though I recall that jars aren't a thing android does either, just like it doesn't 'do' class files).